# Finding indices that fall between given ranges

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to find the elements in `dataX` and `dataY` which are between boundaries (B4X1, B4X2) and (B4Y1, B4Y2)

```
import numpy as np 

B4X1 = 50.
B4X2 = 60.


B4Y1 = 150.
B4Y2 = 160.

dataX = np.array([40, 25, 50, 60, 55])
dataY = np.array([140, 125, 150, 160, 155])

Expected result is:

result = array([False, False, False, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

How would be the faster way of doing it?

I did as:

```
OK = (B4X1 < dataX < B4X2) & (B4Y1 < dataY < B4Y2)

print OK
```

But the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\je\Desktop\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    OK = (B4X1 < dataX < B4X2) & (B4Y1 < dataY < B4Y2)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut notation `B4X1 < dataX < B4X2` doesn't work.

You need to do the following:

```
OK = (B4X1 < dataX) & (dataX < B4X2) & (B4Y1 < dataY) & (dataY < B4Y2)
```

EDIT:

Since timing was brought up:

```
In [23]: dataX = np.random.randint(200, size=100)

In [24]: dataY = np.random.randint(200, size=100)

In [25]: %timeit OK = (B4X1 < dataX) & (dataX < B4X2) & (B4Y1 < dataY) & (dataY < B4Y2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.6 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit OK = np.logical_and.reduce([B4X1<dataX,dataX<B4X2,B4Y1<dataY,dataY<B4Y2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.7 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit for i in dataX: OK = (B4X1 < i and i < B4X2) and (B4Y1 < i and i < B4Y2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 449 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit for i in dataX: OK = (B4X1 < i and i < B4X2) and (B4Y1 < i and i < B4Y2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 329 µs per loop
```

Comment: Is this really the optimal way of doing it? It's going to do up to 2N more compares than should be required.

Comment: @user3467349 I'm certain there's a faster way, but this approach is usually fast enough and you don't have to worry about striping and such. Numpy is pretty well written in this regard. Besides, if what you wrote gives an error, it doesn't matter how fast it is.

Comment: @user3467349 Since you brought up compares, you should also bring up branching, which can be more expensive than simply performing an `and` operation. See the timing info I provided above. Also, remember that numpy does its inner loops in native code, and not in python, so doing it "the long way" is actually more efficient here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to apply a `logical_and` operation on all of your conditions as an elegant way you can use `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
>>> np.logical_and.reduce([B4X1<dataX,dataX<B4X2,B4Y1<dataY,dataY<B4Y2])
array([False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```